# Вылетает приложение во время перехода между страницами

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windowsphone

У меня есть 2 страницы: `MainPage` и `Page2`. У меня есть переход в `MainPage`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    this.Loaded += (a, b) => { Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2)); };  
}
```

Когда я запускаю приложение через Visual Studio, все работает хорошо, когда я открываю в телефоне или в эмуляторе самостоятельно, приложение вылетает во время перехода.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Если я делаю это неправильно, подскажите, как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
Loaded += async ( a, b ) =>
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync( Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
    {
        Frame.Navigate( typeof( Page2 ) );
    } );
};
```